# Are there major security concerns related to making an ajax call and returning a true?

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication

My code takes a user name and password and passes it via ajax to my server side code that authenticates on the domain. the returned string is true. Is it possible for hackers to somehow inject a true response to enter the site?
the c#

```
if (Request.Form["MethodName"] == "auththenticate")
{
    string u = Request.Form["username"].ToString();
    string p = Request.Form["password"].ToString();

    bool valid = false;
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        valid = context.ValidateCredentials(u, p);
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(valid);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

success function of the ajax call:success: function (json) {

```
if (json == "True") {      
    $("#loginDialog").dialog("destroy"); var authenticated = true 
} else {
    $("#username").val("");
    $("#password").val("");
    $("#fail").css(visibility, "visible");
}
```

Comment: Why not just return a `204` code? ;-)

Comment: As long as you are not letting the javascript tell the server script that this is a authentic user on subsequent requests then its fine